# When i'm navigating forward and backwards through my app, my listview gets unresponsive.. anyone knows what it could be?

Tags: android, android-listview, xamarin

I have a pretty simple/standard android application, with a mainscreen which calls a new fragment with a listview inside it, when i click on a listview it opens some information on that listview (just text)..

The listview has some photo's that are being loaded and the text aswell, when i press the backbutton or the actionbar backbutton (appcompat v7 bar) forwards and backwards a few times...

almost always after a few times the listview and actionbar get unresponsive, they both hang and after 5 seconds he opens the last listviewitem i clicked... (even when i clicked multiple while unresponsive)...

As if it's hanging in loading something, is this some common bug?

the onbackpressed and onresume are not modified/overridden, so it's just standard as it should be..?

ps: i'm creating it in Xamarin (C#) but it shouldnt be a difference with Java android i guess

Comment: Make sure you free up the image resource as it goes out of the view and also load image into memory only in the required size. You may check out - [Xamarin Android Image Auto Slider and OOM Issue Handled](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/1038358/Xamarin-Android-Image-Auto-Slider-and-OOM-Issue-Ha)

Answer (score 0):

if you are loading the images in a background thread (what is a good practice..), the threads won't be destroyed if you leave the activity or just switch the fragment.
If you go back to the fragment with the listview again, you will propably start threads for loading the images again while the olds threads are still active.

If this is the case you will have to wait until the old threads are ready (which will affect nothing anymore), to start with the threads for your current listview. This might explain your observation.

I had this problem in one of my apps and solved it by stopping the background threads when leaving the listview.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you start profiling your app with Xamarins Profiler and Android Device Monitor to see what is really going on. Anything else would be guessing.